# Search Algorithms used in salesforce Query search (SOQL and SOSL)

Tags: apex, trigger

I was trying to understand what algorithms are being used for SOSL and SOQL by salesforce if all the fields (5 fields) which are queried are id fields and how can we segregate and improve the where clause which are being passed to get the most optimal result.
Articles, Suggestion with mathematical formula interpretation would be great help.

Lets take an example below example:

- We have an junction object with 5 lookups on account (10000 Records), opportunity (100000 Records), user (100 Records), case (100000 Records) and lead (100000) Records.
- from an input source we got a array of account, opportunity,user,case and lead respectively.
- now if i query on the junction object what would be the best sequence of where clause and can we predict an analogy as per that.

Regards
Stay Safe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the best resources for optimizing SOQL and SOSL (and for performance in large data volume orgs in general) is [Best Practices for Deployments with Large Data Volumes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_large_data_volumes_bp.meta/salesforce_large_data_volumes_bp/ldv_deployments_introduction.htm), specifically the section [Using SOQL and SOSL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_large_data_volumes_bp.meta/salesforce_large_data_volumes_bp/ldv_deployments_techniques_using_soql_and_sosl.htm).

Lookup fields are automatically indexed, yielding performant SOQL queries. If you're querying based on lookup fields, the biggest things you can do are

- Ensure that any *other* filters (not against relationship fields) that you use in your `WHERE` clause are also indexed.
- Ensure that any collections (`Set`, `List`) of `Id` values you query against do not contain `null`, and that you don't have any other clauses whose filters may be `null`. This is because

  > Executing a query with a WHERE filter that has null values for picklists or foreign key fields doesn’t use the index, and should be avoided.
- Be aware of how selectivity limits can result in an index not being used. See [Indexes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_large_data_volumes_bp.meta/salesforce_large_data_volumes_bp/ldv_deployments_infrastructure_indexes.htm#standard_and_custom_indexed_fields). This is a concern primarily if the inbound collections of related objects are extremely large relative to the total object size.

Comment: Is it worth mentioning data skew?

Answer (score 0):

The order of the filters in the where clause don't matter. Salesforce automatically optimizes the filters for optimal order. This happens at the database layer, so as an outside developer, we'll never know exactly how it does it, but it works well.

In addition, lookup fields always use indexes, so we never have full-table scans, but instead much faster index scans. This is one of those cases where, as long as what you're filtering on in indexed, you don't need to worry about the specific order. Salesforce will (generally) always do the correct thing.

Unlike some database systems, Salesforce always optimizes all queries using metadata from each object. For example, in your hypothetical example, Salesforce will know that the user index is the smallest and (probably) select it first. As the object sizes change, running the same query may result in a different internal order.

Salesforce.com engineers are constantly monitoring the algorithms used to generate the queries and fixing problems, so as external developers, we don't need to worry much about optimizing our queries. Simply following the [best practices](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_large_data_volumes_bp.meta/salesforce_large_data_volumes_bp/ldv_deployments_best_practices_soql_and_sosl.htm) (using indexed fields when possible, avoiding NOT IN filters, and avoiding "contains" or "ends with" filters), Salesforce will have optimal performance.

Comment: We have found (even in the last 12 months) that order is important and that putting indexed fields, such as IDs, before non-indexed fields has a massive impact on SOQL execution times.

Comment: @PhilW Interesting. I haven't noticed that. If there are problems, support should probably be involved. Then again, the algorithm isn't perfect, so it might just be a gap in how the query optimizer should work.